# How to fix linker error when compiling XV6?

Tags: c, xv6

I have three files in my XV6: testmain.c, foo.h, and foo.c :

foo.h :

```
extern void myfunction(void)
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
void myfunction(void){
   printf(1, "HelloWorld"); }
```

testmain.c:

```
 #include "foo.h" 
 int main(void){
    myfunction();
    return 0 ; }
```

I am getting undefined reference error for myfunction() in test_main . I know I need to change something in Makefile for XV6, but I don't know what. that's what I have changed in XV6 Makefile:

```
UPROGS=\
    _cat\
    _echo\
    _forktest\
    _grep\
    _init\
    _kill\
    _ln\
    _ls\
    _mkdir\
    _rm\
    _sh\
    _stressfs\
    _usertests\
    _wc\
    _zombie\ 
    _foo\
    _testmain\
```

Comment: Show us the whole makefile, and what compile and link commands 
 are generated by the makefile.  Also, are foo.c and testmain.c in the same directory?

Comment: @Leonard https://github.com/jeffallen/xv6/blob/master/Makefile is the XV6 make file. However I changed the UPROGS as I mentioned above. This is the compile error : undefined reference to 'foo' - yes they are in the same directory

Comment: Well I'm not running XV6 so I can't test this, but try adding foo.o to the list of OBJs at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You need several changes in `Makefile`:

- Indicate that you want to create `_testmain` program,
- Tell what `_testmain` dependencies are (if apply).

#### add `_testmain` in programs list:

```
UPROGS=\
    _testmain\
    _cat\
    _crash\ 
    _echo\
    _factor\
    ....
```

#### `_testmain` dependencies:

Since your `_testmain` program depends on two files, you must create a special rule telling that to builder (I make this rule from `_%: %.o $(ULIB)` rule):

```
_testmain: testmain.o foo.o $(ULIB)

    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e main -Ttext 0x1000 -o $@ $^
    $(OBJDUMP) -S $@ > $*.asm
    $(OBJDUMP) -t $@ | sed '1,/SYMBOL TABLE/d; s/ .* / /; /^$$/d' > $*.sym
```